# Convert first letter to uppercase in word containing diacritics

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code where the input of first-name last-name will be converted to lowercase then the first letters of each word will be converted to uppercase and then swap place.

However, I ran into an inconvenience where special characters(not certain with the term) were not being processed.

Input: oNdřej rasZka
Desired output: Raszka,Ondřej
What I'm getting: OndŘEj Raszka

The "ŘE" of  OndŘEj was not processed properly same with other available special characters, is there any way to solve this?

```
<div>
  <textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="fullName" class= ""></textarea>
</div>

<button id="splitName">Click</button>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div class= "border" id="result"></div>
```

```
var splitName = document.getElementById("splitName");

splitName.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '';

        var value = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
  
  
  //CASE CONVERT//
            var value2 = value.toLowerCase();
            value2 = value2.replace(/\b./g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); });

        

    value2.split('\n').forEach(fullname => {
    var spaceIndex = fullname.indexOf(" ");
    var firstname;
    var lastname;
    if (spaceIndex == -1) {
      lastname = fullname;
      lastname = "";
    } else {
      firstname = fullname.substring(0, spaceIndex);
      lastname = fullname.substr(spaceIndex + 1);       
    }

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += lastname + " " + firstname+ "<br>";
             


  });
};
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Comment: @SaiKiranKrishnaMurthy It looks like @Ced is trying to capitalise multiple words as their variable is called `fullName`. The answer is very similar but maybe a slightly different one

Comment: `\b.` matches the special characters, the replace function returns those back to upper case. Use `/^.|\s./g` to match the first characters in the white-space-separated words. If another word delimiter can be used, the things will become more tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice off the first character, call toUpperCase on it and then concatenate it back onto the remainder of the string.

```
function capitalise(input) {
  return `${input[0].toUpperCase()}${input.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`
}
```

This method avoids you converting everything to lower case and then having to switch the first character back. I suspect your regex is what's causing the issue, as it's likely reading characters that aren't there.

Alternatively, if you want to capitalise each name and you know the separating character you can do something like:

```
function capitalise(input, separator) {
  const wordArray = input.split(separator);
  const output = wordArray.map(word => `${word[0].toUpperCase()}${word.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`);

  return output.join(separator);
}
```

Comment: That's what OP is doing: `.replace(/\b./g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); });`

Comment: @Andreas It's the same method but doesn't use the regex which is (I suspect) what's causing the false-positive matches